# link to an new page and stop at a specified scrolling point for that newly opened page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created an anchor link and set the href attriubute to the URL I want it to jump to. However, I do not know how I can let users directly see the middle part of the website with that URL in the new window the browser just created.
  BTW, my web browser cannot run Jquery for some reason. I do not know why. Thus I prefer the answer without using Jquery.  :-(
 Is there anyone who can help me? Appreciate it.

Comment: Can you show an example of the link?

Answer (score 1):

Set an `id` on the element you want to scroll to, then put `#yourid` on the end of the URL.

```
<a href="test.html#foo">Link to foo</a>

<p id="foo">Bar</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to redirect the user from **index.html** to *middle part of* **index2.html**. Add *an id to that middle part (say 'mid')*. Then you can use the link

```
<a href="index2.html#mid">link</a>
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

div#mid {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div><a href="#mid">link</a></div>

  <div id="mid">2</div>

  <div>3</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the anchor you want to scroll to on the new page is an id, #anchor and your url is example.com, you can just do example.com#anchor

Answer (score 0):

First create the link with `#position` where you want to jump at.

```
<a href="#goThere">Link</a>
```

Now locate the content and give it an ID same one which used in the `href="#goThere` where you want your link to jump at on click. For example;

```
<div class="content">
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <div id="goThere">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
 elit. Illum error nesciunt recusandae id esse odit illo quo odio similique optio, iste non ipsum eius, nostrum temporibus praesentium enim harum soluta.
  </div.
</div>
```

This will jump to the location on same page. For new page just give the full url like `href="newpage.html#goThere"` or `example.com/#goThere`